# iterate over a list as iterator in python

Tags: python, iterator, generator

I have a function which returns a list of objects (I used the code below for example). Each object has attribute called text:

```
def mylist():
    mylist = []
    for i in range(5):
        elem = myobject(i)
        mylist.append(elem)
    return mylist

for obj in mylist():
    print obj.text
```

How can I rewrite this code so mylist() returned each iteration new value and I iterate over iterator? In other words how can I reuse here a mylist in python so use it like xrange()?

Comment: Given that you've included [tag:generator], what's the problem?

Comment: No problem) I just want to make from mylist -- > xmylist. As from range --> xrange. I just dont know how to iterate over generator. Just change word "return" to "yield" not work: AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'text'. Sorry for stupid question. I am new to this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood right, you're looking for [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators):

```
def mylist():
    for i in range(5):
        elem = myobject(i)
        yield elem
```

Complete code for you to play with:

```
class myobject:
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.text = 'hello ' + str(i)

def mylist():
    for i in range(5):
        elem = myobject(i)
        yield elem

for obj in mylist():
    print obj.text
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a generator expression:

```
mylist = (myobject(i) for i in range(5))
```

This will give you an actual generator but without having to declare a function beforehand.

Please note the usage of parentheses instead of brackets to denote a generator comprehension instead of a list comprehension

Comment: Great solution))) Real pythonish))) But my problem how to convert list of object (any objects) to iterator. But anyway - thanks)

Answer (score 3):

What georg said, or you can return the iter of that list

```
def mylist():
    mylist = []
    for i in range(5):
        mylist.append(myobject(i))
    return iter(mylist)
```

probably not a good idea to use your function name as a variable name, though :)

Comment: While this answer is 'correct' in that there is an iterator it differs from the others in *when* the evaluation takes place - it's a lazy wrapper over an eager evaluation. (I believe the OP is looking to avoid the eager range-like bit.)

Answer (score 0):

```
llist = [0,4,5,6] 
ii = iter(llist) 
while (True): 
    try: 
        print(next(ii)) 
    except StopIteration: 
        print('End of iteration.') 
        break
```